# Ошибка в вызове sscanf: "Access violation at adress"

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос. При попытке записи в файл (`TestFile.txt`) по методу запись в начало файла, я создаю временный файл, в который идет запись, затем открываю `TestFile.txt` и копирую всю инфу из него во временный файл с добавлением в конец, удаляю `TestFile.txt`, а временный переименовываю в `TestFile.txt`. Однако при попытке первой записи `TestFile.txt` является пустым, может ли быть такое, что программа не может прочитать в нем какие-либо данные и выдает ошибку?

Код:

```
FILE *in;
char ss[200];

in=fopen("TestFile_temp.txt", "at");
sprintf(ss,"%s %d %d %d %d %s %d %d \n",
A.City,A.type,A.floor,A.rooms,A.space,A.street,A.houseNum,A.flatNum);
fputs(ss,in);
fclose(in);

in=fopen("TestFile.txt", "rd");
sscanf(ss,"%s %d %d %d %d %s %d %d \n",
A.City,A.type,A.floor,A.rooms,A.space,A.street,A.houseNum,A.flatNum);
fgets(ss,200,in);
fclose(in);     //(A это структура данных содержащая инфу о квартире )
```

Текст ошибки:

> `Project Project1.exe raised expection class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at adress 32664079 in module 'CC3260MT.DLL' Write of address 00000003' Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.`

Comment: А где инициализация "A" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция sscanf требует указателей. То есть, нужно писать так:

```
sscanf(ss,"%s %d %d %d %d %s %d %d n", &A.City, &A.type, &A.floor, &A.rooms, &A.space, &A.street, &A.houseNum, &A.flatNum);
```

Comment: Исправил как надо, теперь с той же ошибкой указывает на fgets=(

Comment: А файл там открыт? Может нет?

Comment: А как проверить?

Comment: где то так

    in = fopen(....);
    if (in == NULL) {
      printf("ERROR!\n");
      return 0;
    }
    sscanf....

Comment: А точно!) Как я сам не додумался)
И так получилось, что сообщение с надписью "ошибка" все-таки вылазит(

Comment: А это значит, что файл не существует или нельзя открыть его.

Comment: Если Вы открываете несуществующий файл только для чтения, то он создан не будет! Соответственно fopen возвратит NULL. Нужно открывать с опцией для чтения и записи ("r+", "w+").